# Retrieve the Jetty instance in Dropwizard 2.0.0

Tags: java, dropwizard, armeria

We have a project made in Dropwizard version 2.0.0-RC, where we use REST-endpoints. After some issues we decided to use gRPC instead of using REST. There is a couple of 3rd party libraries to connect gRPC to Dropwizard, but we believe they are a bit outdated and not useable. So we are thinking about implementing Armeria and their GRPC solution.

To implement this, I need the Jetty instance to attach the GRPC.

This is how I can solve it (Mix between GRPC and Armeria):

```java
Server server = Server.builder()
  .http(8080)
  .service(GrpcService.builder()...build())
  .serviceUnder("/", JettyService.forServer(jettyServer))
  .build();
server.start().join();
```

So I need the `jettyServer` to be the instance of Jetty with the type of `org.eclipse.jetty.server`. The rest of the code is Armerias way of embedding Jetty. [Link to embedding jetty.](http://line.github.io/armeria/server-servlet.html#embedding-jetty)

How can I retrieve the instance of Jetty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using Dropwizard lifecycles to get the server.

```java
// variable server is of type org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server
environment.lifecycle().addServerLifecycleListener(new ServerLifecycleListener() {
    @Override
    public void serverStarted(Server server) {
      // ....
    }
});
```

With the instance, you can use Armeria to attach gRPC

Comment: If anyone is having similar objective/goal - check the Dropwizard's User Manual and the last topic "Dropwizard Internals". The particular question is covered at the end: https://www.dropwizard.io/en/release-1.3.x/manual/internals.html#jetty-lifecycle

Comment: Also from architecture/code structure point of view it is better to use extend/replace the ServerFactory implementations. The provided ones are here: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/server. Here is how another project is achieving the same goal: https://github.com/msteinhoff/dropwizard-grpc/tree/master/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/grpc/server

Comment: Do you know how that is handled at 2.0.0, @zloster?

Comment: Here is how I've made a quick check. The master branch is the 2.0.x release, the 1.3.x release has it own branch. Compare the two branches about changes in the bootstrap interfaces: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/commits/master/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/server You will see very few and subtle changes there. Also take a look at the wiki: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/wiki/Upgrade-guide-1.3.x-to-2.0.x I guess the changes there will be reflected also in the docs source at some point: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/docs/source/manual

Comment: Also note this: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/wiki/Upgrade-guide-1.3.x-to-2.0.x#dropwizard-bill-of-materials-bom This will be one of the most visible changes (from a developer perspective).

Comment: @zloster Thanks for all the links. I was able to implement this by overriding the ServerFactory

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the links provided in the comments of the other answer and put this PR together in Armeria project for adding a dropwizard module.

https://github.com/line/armeria/pull/2236

It currently targets 1.3.x rather than 2.0, but once a stable release exists, it'll need upgraded

Edit: PR was accepted and merged